# Add someone else to employer-sponsored health insurance?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance

My brother recently started working at the Internal Revenue Service (IRS). He tells me that he can add anyone to the health insurance that covers him.

Can he add me to his health insurance? I'm an adult.

Comment: This might be the most unusual of all the questions tagged `irs`

Comment: Do you live in the same household?

Comment: Probably not unless he is your legal guardian and you are under 26. If you're over 26 then a disability would enable you to be under his insurance if they are your guardian. https://massairc.org/factsheets/healthcare-coverage-for-adults-with-asd-frequently-asked-questions-for-parents/. It sounds like their excitement for a new job has clouded their focus during employee orientation.

Comment: Despite the amusement factor in the [tag:irs] tag, it's not appropriate here (as the IRS is simply the employer), so removed.

Comment: I would ask your brother to double-check the fine print on his specific plan. https://www.jobs.irs.gov/resources/benefits-programs/worklife-programs/use-our-benefits-your-benefit refers to https://www.opm.gov/healthcare-insurance/healthcare/ which refers to https://www.opm.gov/healthcare-insurance/healthcare/reference-materials/reference/family-members/ which limits eligibility to *spouse (including a valid common law marriage) and children under age 26, including legally adopted children, recognized natural (born out of wedlock) children and stepchildren* as well as a few extra fringe cases.

Answer (score 13):

The correct answer is "he needs to verify with his employer if this is possible."

But, does it really make sense that a company would let an employee add anyone who is not a dependant/spouse/child to be added to their plan?

Comment: I wonder if this is an easier approach to allow employees' domestic partners/non-traditional spouses/etc. to be covered rather than requiring documentation or court red tape? But I don't think the IRS is afraid of red tape... :)

Comment: my brother was able to add his girlfriend to his insurance plan several years ago.  While apparently not as wide open as what the OP is asking about; my assumption has always been that offering coverage to domestic partners of any sex was done pre-gay marriage as a way to offer support while trying to minimize the potential backlash from opponents.

Comment: Maybe my negative rhetorical question was uncalled for. I did not mean it to be unkind or off-putting. An employer has a cost burden to add a non-employee to its health plan. I am retired, but work part time, 13 hrs/wk. When I asked about the potential to go 1/2 time, I was kindly told that HR was trying to avoid that due to the expense, effectively 2X the health cost for 2 half timers vs one full time. And Dan, you've shown that it might be possible, so that just means a flat out "No" is wrong. But only the employer can offer the "yes". (Unless another employee is a member, I suppose)

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica I think it makes as much sense as any other job perks that might be offered --- beyond those legally required, of course. The cost-benefit analysis will vary based on the industry and type of employee that they're trying to attract.

Answer (score 4):

The exact answer to this question depends on the employer's policy and insurance plan's rules, so the only way to answer it is by asking your (brother's) HR department.

Generally speaking, yes, this can be possible.  Legally, there's nothing stopping an employer and/or insurer from adding anyone you want to your insurance plan (if you're willing to pay for it).

However, there is one important tax implication: your brother will owe extra income tax on any portion of the insurance premium that is paid for by his employer, and must pay any employee share with post-tax dollars.  This differs from self, spouse, and child coverage, where you usually don't have to pay any income tax on health insurance.

This tax implication is why some companies/plans do not allow you to add anyone other than a spouse or child.  The rules are complex and they don't want to deal with the paperwork.

Comment: Given that the organization in question promulgates these rules, maybe they do it so they can dedicate analysts to making sure the regulations make sense.  Dogfooding the tax code, kinda.

Comment: @user662852 I highly doubt that is the reason, since it's a very progressive idea (and any public institution is conservative by nature). I would believe that these complicated rules were created to ensure that the IRS or another government agency can fulfill some orthogonal obligation, since government orgs often have weird requirements.